# Time driven function in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to download the data from a website every hour using Google script. The code is shown as below. When I manually run the function CSV_sgj, I can receive the desired information in email. But when I set the function as time driven (every hour), what I get are all #VALUE!.

I found a similar question and tried to change

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

to

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AtAYfCLk3-h7dDBnckdSZkNXbkZBLXBHV200SGtuZnc");
```

but it still does not work.

Many thanks in advance for help!

The full code is below.

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
};

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the readRows() function specified above.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */

function CSV_sgj() {
  readRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:N32");
  var data = range.getValues();

  var csv = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    csv += data[i].join(",") + "\r\n";
  }
  var csvFiles = [{fileName:"PSI5.csv", content:csv}]
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "CSV", "", {attachments: csvFiles}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AtAYfCLk3-h7dDBnckdSZkNXbkZBLXBHV200SGtuZnc");
```

the returned value is a `spreadsheet object` and what you want is a `sheet object`...
So you have to get the sheet by its name or by its index number. I suggest you change the variable names accordingly to keep things clear :

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AtAYfCLk3-h7dDBnckdSZkNXbkZBLXBHV200SGtuZnc");
var sheet = ss.openByName('sheet1');// or any name you use (a string)
//or by its index
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0] ;// 0 is the index of the first sheet in the spreadsheet (integer)
```